# How can I see commit messages when updating in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, svn

Is there a way to see the commit message tied to a specific revision when I'm updating to it - or all the commit messages if I'm updating more than one revision up? I constantly update my local copy and don't know what changes were made to it.